# Autocomplete Mui Testing, simulate change doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, material-ui

I need to simulate an onChange event with enzyme to update a state's component that is not working, I share the component's code in order to be helped.

Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
    
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
];
    
const Counter = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({ title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 });

  const handleAutocomplete = (e, item) => {
    setValue(item);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {value && (
        <p id="option">{value.title}</p>
      )}
      <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        name="tags"
        debug
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        onChange={handleAutocomplete}
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

test component.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';

describe('<Counter />', () => {
  it('shoult update component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Counter />);
    const autocomplete = wrapper.find('input');
    console.log(autocomplete.debug());
    autocomplete.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'The Shawshank Redemption' }});
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toEqual('The Shawshank Redemption');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't help you with `enzyme` since I'm no longer using it. In part because it is not as robust with simulating events as other libraries.

I personally only use `@testing-library/react` which is also what Material-UI is using. Then you can write

```
const { getByRole } = render(<Counter />);
const autocomplete = getByRole('textbox');
fireEvent.change(autocomplete, { target: { value: 'The Shawshank Redemption' } });
expect(autocomplete.value).to.equal('The Shawshank Redemption');
```